# Converting a Ruby application to Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, activerecord, rspec

Let's say we have a ruby class like this:

```
class Song
  attr_reader :id, :title, :author, :path

  def initialize(id, title, author, path)
    @id = id
    @title= title
    @author= author
    @path = path
  end

  def change_title(new)
    @title = new
  end

  def change_path(new)
    @path = new
  end

  # other functions here, some operations and stuff

end
```

If we were to "convert" it to an Rails ActiveRecord one, what should we do? (examples please) I am quite new to this and don't quite understand how it works, so figured I might ask here.

The second part of this is, we have lots of tests (RSpec for example)

```
before(:each){
  @song = Song.new(Random.rand(100), 
                   'Some song', 'Some author', 'C:/song.mp3')
}    

it 'change songs path' do
  new_path = 'D:/new_path/something.mp3'
  @song.change_path(new_path)
  expect(@song.path).to eq new_path
end
```

Could you provide me with some examples of how could we produce testing data for the tests and how should we change the tests, like using Fixtures or Factory_girl or etc.

Sorry for quite stupid questions for some of you maybe, because there is documentation, but I find it hard to understand, so thought maybe actual situation like I provided might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my opininion, you should keep separately your business logic and data. So that the possible solution would be described in few steps:

1. Create a new ActiveRecord models, e.g. Song
2. Add *glue* module, that would perform read/write operations between AR model and your custom class attributes.

The benefit of this solution is that you don't need to rewrite your business layer and tests, only *glue* module should be mixined to your classes.

Comment: Well as much as I understand the data will have to be stored in a database.

Comment: yes, the purpose of models is to perform data store, and your business logic remains untouched.

Comment: Yes I know the logic should not change, but there should be some simple changes like inheriting ActiveRecord::Base and stuff like that, but I don't quite fully understand what else should change and also, should I place my tests and logic classes to the corresponding 'models' folders?

Comment: you shouldn't move your logic classes to models folder, instead of create models separately. So that models are responsible for persistent layer and rest of your existing code should invoke glue module's read/write functions that works with model

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your project, but generally, Rails' models should correspond to models in your Ruby app. Possibly all you'll need to do is just inherit your `Song` class from `ActiveRecord::Base`, create table "songs" in database (usually it is done with migrations), and here you are!

What @funnydaredevil talks about is decoupling persistent layer from logic layer. It's common decision to reduce complexity of big applications. But I think that on first steps of app life it is overengineering.

About test: surely you can use Factory Girl.

```
before do
  @song = FactoryGirl.build(:song)
end

# factories/song.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :song do
    id { Random.rand(100) }
    title  'Some song'
    author 'Some author'
    path 'C:/song.mp3'
  end
end
```